# Disable scrolling parent page when playing a game in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very simply game page, where I have games in iframes. I want to disable scrolling on the main page when I am playing a game in iframe. I have tried overflow:hidden but it disables totally scrolling, which is useless.

When the page is longer than the screen pressing the down arrow scrolls the page down, and makes the game impossible to play.

Is there a basic way to disable scrolling during playing?

Game input listener:

```
/*
 This simply library keeps the state of the currently
 pressed keys by using keydown and keyup event handlers.
 */
(function() {
    var pressedKeys = {};
    function setKey(event, status) {
        var code = event.keyCode;
        var key;
        switch(code) {
        case 32:
            key = 'SPACE'; break;
        case 37:
            key = 'LEFT'; break;
        case 38:
            key = 'UP'; break;
        case 39:
            key = 'RIGHT'; break;
        case 40:
            key = 'DOWN'; break;
        default:
            // Convert ASCII codes to letters
            key = String.fromCharCode(code);
        }
        pressedKeys[key] = status;
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        setKey(e, true);
        e.stoppreventDefault();
    });
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: ? Do you want the `overflow:hidden` to be temporary (only while playing)?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable it only while playing becouse When the page is longer than the screen (comments, etc.) pressing the down arrow scrolls the page down, and makes the game impossible to play.

Comment: Consider using [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in your down-arrow event handler to stop the event from reaching the higher level container (i.e. `window`).

Comment: Note that setting `overflow:hidden` on the main page has the (possibly unlikely) side effect where if your game frame is below the first screen height (perhaps due to headers, banner ads, the user having 50 toolbars installed, using a smaller window, or whatever else that may prevent the full game window from being shown), then it will be cut off without a way for users to scroll down.

Comment: ps: you also can let the game with `position:fixed;` (wich ignores scroll).

Comment: or yet, let the comments and etc in a separated div with its own scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) in your down-arrow event handler to stop the event from reaching the higher level container (i.e. `window`).

For example, in the `keydown` handler of the game:

```
function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 40 /* Down arrow */) {
    // Do your game stuff here.
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

In case you have higher level elements that require the down-arrow event (and you can't modify those functions to `stopPropagation`) you can also use [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default action (scrolling):

```
function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 40 /* Down arrow */) {
    // Do your game stuff here.
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to or can't modify the game code, you can also swallow all down-arrow events at the window level.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 40 /* Down arrow */) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the "default" action from happening, in this case, scrolling down.
  }
}, false);
```

Note that setting `overflow:hidden` on the main page has the (possibly unlikely) side effect where if your game frame is below the first screen height (perhaps due to headers, banner ads, the user having 50 toolbars installed, using a smaller window, or whatever else that may prevent the full game window from being shown), then it will be cut off without a way for users to scroll down.

Comment: preventDefault() solved my problem, You saved my day :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet uses javascript to set the css overflow hide/auto when clicking in a button.

**UPDATE:** *Instead of a button, you can set these actions to be triggered on iframe focus.*
Example: `<iframe src="http://www.yourgame.com" onfocus="offf()" onblur="onn()"></iframe>`

```js
function offf(){
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowY = "hidden";
}

function onn(){
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflowY = "auto";
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  background:honeydew;
  width:100%;
  height:150%;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#a {
  position:fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background: gold;  
}

#b {
  left: 140px;
  top: 10px;
  position:fixed;
  background: hotpink;  
}
```

```html
<div><button id=a onClick="offf()">PLAY (hide scroll)</button><button id=b onClick="onn()">STOP (show scroll)</button></div>
```

Comment: it disables just for a second when I am starting to play the page is starting to scroll again.

Comment: You mean the focus event? Sorry I thought it was going to work but I have no way tro try. Anyway, you still can use it on the 'play' button;